# Zoom in and out in Virtual Machine (Windows)

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, parallels, zoom, screen-recorder

I have a Mac and I use `Parallels Desktop` where Windows 10 is installed. I want to record a video from screen in Windows 10 (Microsoft Excel). Sometimes, I need to zoom in and out to show a specific area on the screen. Does anyone know how to do it by keyboard or by mouse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The free
[ZoomIt](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/zoomit)
can be used for it :

> ZoomIt is a screen zoom and annotation tool for technical presentations that include application demonstrations. ZoomIt runs unobtrusively in the tray and activates with customizable hotkeys to zoom in on an area of the screen, move around while zoomed, and draw on the zoomed image.

[image]